# Android HTTP Authentication error

Tags: java, android, http, http-authentication

```
final HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpPost hPost = new HttpPost(
        "http://xxx.xxx");
try {
    hPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    hPost.setHeader("Content-type",
            "application/json");
    hPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(JSON));
    // execute request
    final HttpResponse response = hClient
            .execute(hPost);
    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Android returns 05-16 20:02:52.784: W/DefaultRequestDirector(15642): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {} and I don't know how to fix it. Where is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: it looks as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114455/authentication-error-when-using-httppost-with-defaulthttpclient-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the Http parameters as following:

```
HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();

HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000); // Timeout

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);
```

For the http post and response you can try the following code. Kindly customize according to your needs (for example set your string parameters)

```
HttpResponse response;
httpClient.getParams().setParameter("Your String", "YourStringValue");
localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(YOurURL);

Log.e("URL", URL); //just to check 

httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY,CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);

StringEntity tmp = null;

httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

tmp = new StringEntity(inputJObject.toString(), "UTF-8");

httpPost.setEntity(tmp);

response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);


Log.i(TAG, response.getStatusLine().toString()); // Examine the response status


HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();  // Get hold of the response entity
```

Comment: Didn't change anything at all :(

Comment: So, are you saying timeout configuration is necessary here? @peter_ziegler

Answer (score 0):

I had this warning as well, but it did not caused any particular problems, the request still goes fine.

However I stopped getting this error as soon as I started using `AndroidHttpClient` instead of the `DefaultHttpClient`. One uncomfortable thing is that you cannot use `AndroidHttpClient` from UI thread and need to run it on another thread.

Comment: It looks like my request is being denied by this warning and I don't know how to fix it. What is the easiest way to implement this thread solution?

Comment: I would try different http clients that are available on android. each one has different capabilities http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html ... I cannot see which challenges are not answered in your question...

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and resolved it by going back to basics! The error was generated from a request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo. The solution is posted below:

```
            URLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.addRequestProperty("key", API_KEY);
    conn.addRequestProperty("client_id", CLIENT_ID);
    conn.addRequestProperty("client_secret", "");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth " + token);
```

All the add requests are HTTPGET key/values and the setProperty adds an header parameter. As Google API Console does not give a client secret in its current version, I added a balnk string..this solves the AuthToken to user data affair finally :)